# Not Satisfied with Existing Question&Answer but want to avoid duplicate label. Advice?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This scenario has happened several times (ex. my last Stack Overflow question): I have a question. I search and find a similar (or even nigh identical) question which has been answered, often with many upvotes. But even after reading it carefully, I'm not fully satisfied with the answer, either because there's one more bit of information I want to know, I don't understand the answer, or I tried it and it didn't work. So I create a new question, which swiftly gets marked as duplicate and downvoted.

Would it be better to just leave a (possibly long) comment to the original question instead?

Comment: _"Would it be better to just leave a (possibly long) comment to the original question instead?"_ The probably best action is to edit your question and explain why exactly the duplicate answer(s) didn't work for you.

Comment: Agreed: I often will post a list of possible duplicates and list why each one is different: only applies to one genre, the answer is 5+ years old and markets are different, this one focuses on previously published works, etc.  (I'm mostly on Writing.SE, as my examples show.)  It shows that you've done preliminary research.  If someone shows a NEW one that may be a duplicate, consider it carefully -- maybe it works for you, maybe you need to add a new line explaining why that one doesn't work for your situation.  But remember we can't personalize things perfectly - answers need to generalize.