# Unable to merge with previous account because I don't know the profile ID

Tags: support, login, merge-accounts

I registered my original Stack Exchange account using a university email address that is now dead due to my having graduated. I was able to continue using the Stack Exchange account anyway due to my browser automatically signing me in. Unfortunately, that's no longer possible because I was forced to format my computer last month, which is why I made this new account.

The Help Center says that in order to merge accounts, I need to supply the profile ID of my previous one. Unfortunately, I don't know it; the only thing I have to go on is the now-defunct email address.

Does this mean I have to give up on merging and start over again?

Comment: Do you have a link to any of the posts you made under your previous account?

Comment: You may search with your previous profile name in the [`/users`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) page. Currently I can see one profile name starting with [J. D.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/560754/j-d-crutchfield) here.

Comment: That's not it.

As bad as I feel to say it, I can't find my old questions. I would think it would be easy to find; but no. I used to ask questions in the math and programming stack exchanges mainly. As an example, I once asked the question of how to find E(max(X,Y,Z)), where X,Y,Z are uniformly distributed on {(x,y,z):x+y+z=1}. On Meta Stack Exchange, I once asked about what to do when my question has already been asked but I'm not satisfied with the answers; and when I post again it gets marked as duplicate.

Would have thought I should be able to find myself using Google; but no.

Comment: Do you know your uni email? I think that would be good enough to find your old account using the contact link

Comment: J.D., is this it?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336276/not-satisfied-with-existing-questionanswer-but-want-to-avoid-duplicate-label-a

Comment: Yes, that's me. I'll get to filing a Help request to merge accounts then. Thank you Rob!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J.D. your account number is [583848](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/583848/j-d) here on Meta, your network profile number is: [15751701](https://stackexchange.com/users/15751701/j-d?tab=accounts). The second number is the one to use for the "[Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link.